# When does a structure disagree from its elementary substructures?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm trying to gain a better intuitive understanding behind the relationship of substructures and elementary substructures, and I've come to a contradiction that is very obviously false, so there must be some flaw in my understanding somewhere. Below is my thought process, please correct anything I say that is wrong.

From my understanding, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{B}$ then $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ agree on all quantifier-free atomic formulas when evaluated on $A$. That is, the structures say the same things are true for any individual elements of $A$, but not when talking about sweeping claims concerning the whole domain (i.e quantifiers). This is a somewhat strong requirement, as the structures essentially have to be the same aside from a differing domain, i.e when viewed only on $A$ they are essentially the same (is this true?)

From the [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence), my understanding is that elementary substructures must agree on all sentences. So to go from a substructure to elementary substructure, basically all we are adding is the agreement over quantifiers. In particular, you have to add all of the elements of $B$ that satisfy the $\exists$ claims that can be made for $\mathcal{B}$. That is, you have to add any definable subset of $B$. This is because $\mathcal{A}$ now satisfies all $\exists x\phi(x)$, so any $x$ that can be defined by some formula must be in $A$, and $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ agree about everything that can be said for elements in these definable sets. Now $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are basically the same model except that their domains only differ by some non-definable set.

But so when exactly can they differ? The statement would have to be a formula with free variables, say $\psi(x)$, since they agree on all sentences. Suppose the structures disagree on this formula. If $\mathcal{B}\vDash \psi[b]$, then by definition there's some $b\in B$ such that $\mathcal{B}\vDash\exists x\psi(x)$. But $\exists x\psi(x)$ is a sentence, so $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies it, hence $\mathcal{A}\vDash\exists x\psi(x)$. What i'm assuming is the problem here is that for the structures to disagree on $\psi[b]$, we would need $b\in B\setminus A$, meaning $b$ is not definable. So where exactly in the above steps does the non-definability of $b$ break things? Does it not make sense to even say $\psi[b]$? Or is it in the next step, where we say $\mathcal{B}\vDash\exists x\psi(x)$? If so, I thought this was just the [definition of satisfaction for existential sentences](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Predicate_Logic/Satisfaction). I'm clearly very gravely misunderstanding something, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing to note is that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ might disagree on things that you can't express with formulas! This should come as no surprise, since elementarity can only talk about formulas. For instance, $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Q}^2,+)$ are elementary equivalent but nonisomorphic. It might be helpful to work out this example in detail

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I see, that explains why isomorphism is stronger than equivalence. But in general elementary substructures aren’t equivalent right? So for cases where they aren’t equivalent, there’s still *some* formula that can be talked about where they differ right?

Comment: One instructive example is that in the language $\{<\}$, $[0,1]$ is a substructure of $[0,2]$, satisfies all the same sentences (in fact, is isomorphic), but is not an elementary substructure. Also useful: a theory where every substructure is elementary is called [model complete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+complete+theory) and there are several useful equivalent and sufficient conditions.

Comment: (For instance, if you change the language so you have a constant for each of the two endpoints in addition to $\le$, the first order theory of $[0,1]$ is model complete. So, e.g. $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ is an elementary substructure of $[0,1]$.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So $x \mapsto 2x$ is an isomorphism (onto, injective, and an embedding since $\mathcal{L}$ only has $<$). Hence $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ are isomorphic, so automatically elementarily equivalent. However the formula $\phi (x)="\forall y(y<x\vee y=x)"$ is satisfied as $[0.1]\vDash \phi (1)$, whereas $[0,2]\not\vDash\phi (1),$ so $[0,1]$ is not an elementary substructure. Adding the endpoints of $[a,b]$ as constants allows the sentence $"\forall x(x\leq b)"$ and $"\forall x(a\leq x)"$, making every elementary equivalent structure have to be contained within $[a,b]$ and a DLO?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I'm still confused about my final paragraph, though. This clarified to me that elementary equivalence is actually weaker than elementary substructure (equivalence only talks about sentences). But in the case where it's a substructure, where does my argument go wrong?

Comment: @modz Yes, to the first couple sentences, that's the idea. But when we add endpoints for constants, there's not any requirement of containment for elementary equivalence... any DLO with endpoints is elementarily equivalent, regardless of where it lives. What it does change is what it means to be a substructure. $[0,1]$ would no longer be a substructure of $[0,2]$ when the endpoints are included in the language, but it is when they aren't included. It doesn't make sense to talk about $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ disagreeing on a sentence with a parameter from $B\setminus A.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah right, the containment part is wrong because technically the sentence is $\forall x(x\leq c_2)$ and $\forall x(c_1\leq x)$, and then each DLO interprets that at its own endpoints $c_1,c_2$. And it's no longer a substructure because the interpretation of the constant $c_2$ is different. Thank you for the example, this has definitely clarified things for me

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen so applying your example to my confusion in the last paragraph, let $\psi(x)$ be a formula such that $[0,1]\vDash\psi(r)$ for some irrational $r$. Then $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\vDash\exists x\psi(x)$. If there is any rational $q$ satisfying this, then we are good. If not, that means only irrational points satisfy $\psi(x)$. This means $\psi$ defines at least one irrational point, which i'm pretty sure is not possible in this language but have never proved why.

Comment: @modz Sure, if $[0,1]\models \phi(r)$ for some irrational $r$ then there is a $q\in \mathbb Q$ such that $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q\models \phi(q).$ That's true.